# Simulating PIC18F4520 Serial connection using Proteus

Tags: serial-port, simulation, pyserial, proteus

#### Intro

Hy, I am working on a project which uses PIC18F4520 micro-controller to send data to my windows machine. In Windows, I am developing a python GUI using tkinter which will show the data after reading it through Serial port. The micro-controller would be connected to PC using Serial to USB converter.

#### Problem

The Problem is that I don't have that hardware physically available to test it, So I made a Proteus Simulation. Now I want to simulate the virtual port so that I connect to it using pyserial and receive data, How can I achieve that...

THANKS
[image: Proteus simulation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Virtual Serial Port](https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/). With this software, you need to make a virtual port and connect it to Proteus.